# bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Tags: curl

I've installed curl to download a package from AWS server. Not sure, if curl is installed properly because it doesn't work. Installation process completed but curl -V replies bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Would appreciate sharing your experiences and solutions!

```
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/161 kB of archives.
After this operation, 411 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 291697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ curl
bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ curl -V
bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 and libcurl4-openssl 7.68.0-1ubuntu2 is also installed

Comment: Did you previously try to install some unofficial build or build from source, and remove that? If so crossdupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335801/bash-remembers-wrong-path-to-an-executable-that-was-moved (this is not really a programming question or problem)

Comment: yes I did. but it didn't support https so i removed the folder completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the output of both "which curl" and "echo $PATH"? It looks like the PATH doesn't include the directory in with the curl binary is located.

Comment: saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$

Comment: On Ubuntu/bash, use `type $command` not `which $command`

Comment: Thanks! Just for some further details: is this the first time you've installed curl on this machine? The PATH variable does include /usr/bin. Could you double check if there isn't a weird alias for curl? Does "alias curl" return anything?

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 I think they are 2 different commands, but type may indeed be more helpful here.

Comment: Thanks Diogo, well i think so. no alias curl       bash: alias: curl: not found

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 has suggested something helpful in the comments above (Sorry, I'm a new member and not allowed to comment on the original question). If you run "hash", do you see curl there? If so, you can try running "hash -d curl" and try again

Comment: tried command curl it self no difference    bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Comment: yes I ran hash and curl is there (  17 /usr/local/bin/curl) but after hash -d curl, nothing ... saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ hash -d curl
saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$

Comment: And if you run curl again do you still get the same error?

Comment: no its different this time ... saeed@ubuntu-Lenovo-C40-05:~$ curl
curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)
curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_mime_free, version CURL_OPENSSL_4

Comment: You mentioned above "libucrl4-openssl" is also installed, did you manually install it attempting to build from source? If so, I'd try removing it, then removing curl with sudo apt remove curl and reinstalling with sudo apt install curl

Comment: yes I did install it manually. which command should i use for removing libcurl please? because i tried with sudo apt remove libcurl4-openssl and this is the output E: Unable to locate package librul4-openssl

Comment: How did you originally install it?

Comment: i used this command:     sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: OMG! it worked. managed to uninstall libcurl4 and reinstalled the curl using sudo apt install curl and it just worked this time. so happy! Thank you so much for your time and help Diago and Dave! really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help :) If you could please mark the question as answered this may help future people with the same problem and may help me get out of newbie state where I can't comment questions :D

Comment: it worked to some extent but didn't completely resolved the issue. finally I fixed the issue with dpkg command. many thanks anyway.