# curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_cleanup

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl, ubuntu-20.04

I'm facing this issue in my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-charmander-14 X60). I've bought new DELL Latitude 5420. When I type the command "curl" this error shows up.

```
curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_cleanup
```

```
parveen@eagle:~$ sudo apt install curl
[sudo] password for parveen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

It says I already have curl, but I think it's not properly linked.
When I type "man curl" it shows all manual docs about curl. But it's not working, please help me guys.

Comment: Try 'sudo ldconfig'.  There are a couple of posts on the internet about that issue.  Did you originally compile when you installed, or did you use the apt package manager ?

Comment: `sudo apt reinstall libcurl4` may help.

Comment: @S.M. I used the command you have provided but the problem still persists.

Comment: @SScotti I tried this command before after the compilation but it didn't work. First I used the apt package manager but when it didn't work I used the compilation method.

Comment: which curl shows that it's installed here "/usr/local/bin/curl".

Comment: This is improper location. You got mess with the attempt to compile curl. Read the manual in the sources you tried and clean the system.

Comment: Hey guys, I found a solution. First I used this command "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/curl*" to remove curl from this location. Then if I type curl it shows me the error "bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory". Then I used "type curl" which gave me the output "curl is hashed (/snap/bin/curl)". Then I used "hash -d curl", after this my curl started working. Comments from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017956/bash-usr-local-bin-curl-no-such-file-or-directory really helped.

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1376131/701952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. First I used this command `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/curl*` to remove curl from this location. Then if I type curl it shows me the error `bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory`. Then I used `type curl` which gave me the output `curl is hashed (/snap/bin/curl)`. Then I used `hash -d curl`, after this my curl started working.

Comments from [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/66017956/) really helped.

Comment: Hey PS95, welcome to StackOverflow! I edited the formatting of your anwser to increase its readability. Please make sure to have your anwsers properly formatted, so other users have an easier time reading your anwser. You can find info regarding formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: The problem is that snap curl has some issues that break other libraries. Wehn I try to use nvm or rvm for instance, curl seems to be unable to create new files, so I changed to curl from apt... And the problem came back. I am looking for a solution that keeps me from using curl from snap.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it is not properly linked. run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I tried it again, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hey guys, I found a solution.
1). First I used this command "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/curl*" to remove curl from from.

Comment: @PS95 You can add your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

I found a different solution for this problem. I did the following:

1st - find out where was the dependency of curl to libcurl. For some reason there is an issue with this link.

`sudo ldd $(which curl) | grep libcurl`

The output pointed to a link at the following location:

`/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4`

Then I used the command:

`sudo apt-get purge curl`

After purging curl, I checked to see if that file was there, and it was there indeed. So I did the following:

`sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4` (or the path that you got previously)

And than I reinstalled curl with the following commando:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

And everything started working afterwards!!!

### Note: Problem returns after installing certain packages

After installing other packages the problem came back and I had to repeat the process. So it is not a very stable solution. Apparently the file that I deleted was created back again. I am still looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 3):

here's my answer:

1- first remove current curl package

```
sudo apt purge curl
```

2- install curl using snap

```
sudo snap install curl
```

3- remove any older curl files

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/curl*
```

4- link snap curl

```
type curl
#curl is hashed (/snap/bin/curl)
hash -d curl
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2, Dell Latitude 3410.
I was getting the following error.

```
~> curl
curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4
```

I reinstalled curl with snap and it solved my problem.

```
~> sudo apt remove curl
~> sudo snap install curl
```

I also had a curl image with docker if necessary.

```
~> docker run curlimages/curl google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

On Alpine it is just needed to run `apk upgrade` before the install.