# curl version error in RStudio Workbench running on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, curl, libcurl

When restarting R (4.3.1) in a project inside RStudio Workbench running on Ubuntu 20.04 , I get the following error message:

```
Restarting R session...

Project...

$ /usr/local/bin/curl --version ----------------------------------------------
error in running command

Error executing '/usr/local/bin/curl --version': is your copy of curl functional?
```

When I run `locate libcurl.so.4` in the terminal it shows multiple versions of libcurl on the system and in various locations:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.6.0
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.8.0
```

I am not experienced with Linux or curl. Should libcurl be removed from `/usr/local/`?

Comment: Where exactly does that error message appear? Is the error message in the console window or somewhere else? The error message indicates it's looking for the file `curl`, not the shared object (.so) file. It doesn't so much care about the files in the `/lib` folders. Normally the `curl` executable is in a `/bin` folder.

Comment: @MrFlick it prints on to the R Console.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if curl is installed in /usr/local/bin/curl first.

Run the command:

```
file /usr/local/bin/curl
```

If you get something like "cannot open `/usr/local/bin/curl' (No such file or directory)" That means that R is likely looking for curl in /usr/local/bin/ but cannot find it. You can run:

```
where curl
```

To find out where the curl is on the file system and make sure it is installed. You can then add a symbolic link to curl in /usr/local/bin so that the curl binary can be called from the /usr/local/bin folder.

```
ln -s $(where curl) /usr/local/bin/curl
```

Then test that everything is working properly by running:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl --version
```

Symbolic links in linux are basically references to another filename on the system. More on that here if you're curious:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: Thanks @KRSpinelli. `file /usr/local/bin/curl` returns `/usr/local/bin/curl: ELF 64-bit...`. But `where curl` returns `where: command not found`. `/usr/local/bin/curl --version` returns: `/usr/local/bin/curl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/curl: undefined symbol: curl_easy_nextheader`.

Comment: @Greg Seems to be a linking issue, probably something went wrong with the install. Try this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255382/curl-symbol-lookup-error-curl-undefined-symbol-curl-url-cleanup. Or worst case scenario, just delete and reinstall curl.